# Is a "A path to X..." a structural metaphor?

Tags: metaphors

Is "A path to X..." a structural metaphor?

For example,

> A path to happiness.

or

> A path to success.

Answer (score 2):

A path to happiness or to success is a [**structural metaphor**](http://grammar.about.com/od/rs/g/structuralmetaphorterm.htm), but only when **path** is fairly tangible (real and physical) and **happiness** or **success** is abstract (a concept).

However, a path to X may not even be a metaphor:  If the *path to my garden* is muddy, there is no metaphor there.